# Transcribing long audio file in iOS app using google-cloud-speech API

Tags: c#, ios, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-speech

I am trying to implement speech to text API in one of my client's app. The client is a healthcare practitioner.

I have a pre-recorded .wav file and I am able to get the transcribed text for the audio file by sending it's content to speech:recognize API directly (in content parameter) if the file's length is less than 1 minute.

For long audio file (length greater than 1 minute), speech:recognize API gives error and says to use speech:Longrunningrecognize API. Below is the error Json that I receive:

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": 400,
    "message": "Sync input too long. For audio longer than 1 min use LongRunningRecognize with a 'uri' parameter.",
    "status": "INVALID_ARGUMENT"
  }
}
```

When I read the documentation, it says that in order to use speech:Longrunningrecognize API, I need to put the audio file on Google Storage Bucket and set its public access ON by setting it's 'allUser' access.

But, since the client is a healthcare practioner, and don't want to give public access to the files due to HIPAA compliance issues. So, below are my questions:

1. Is it mandatory to put the files on Google Storage Bucket? Can't I directly send the content of long audio file to speech:Longrunningrecognize API with 'Content' parameter instead of sending a GCS url in 'uri' parameter?
2. Currently, I am using "Trial" billing account with 300$ free credit in my account. Is it the case that after moving from trial to paid mode, I can send long audio files directly to speech:recognize or speech:Longrunningrecognize API with 'content' parameter?
3. If I have to put the files on Google Storage bucket, is it necessary to set it's Public access ON? Can't I use the GCS url (gs://bucket-name/audio-file-name.extension) without having to set it's Public access, in a secured way?

Please suggest.

Answer (score 1):

1. Have you tried sending the content to speech:Longrunningrecognize? If it didn't work, what was the error message?
2. It doesn't matter that you are on a "Trial" account.
3. You shouldn't set the files to public access. In order for the speech api to work with a non-public file in your Google Storage bucket, call the speech api using a service account instead of an API key.

Answer (score 0):

1. > Is it mandatory to put the files on Google Storage Bucket? Can't I directly send the content of a long audio file to speech:Longrunningrecognize API with 'Content' parameter instead of sending a GCS url in 'uri' parameter?

   Yes, due to HTTP limit control.
   Audio longer than ~1 minute must use the uri field to reference an audio file in Google Cloud Storage. [View [1] for more explanation.](https://cloud.google.com/speech-to-text/quotas#content)
2. > Currently, I am using "Trial" billing account with 300$ free credit in our account. Is it the case that after moving from trial to paid mode, I can send long audio files directly to speech:recognize or speech:Longrunningrecognize API with 'content' parameter?

   Same limits and policies apply. [View [2] for more explanation on pricing.](https://cloud.google.com/speech-to-text/pricing)
3. > If I have to put the files on Google Storage bucket, is it necessary to set it's Public access ON? Can't I use the GCS url (gs://bucket-name/audio-file-name.extension) without having to set it's Public access, in a secure way?

   No it is not  necessary, use a service account. For further information on how to use it [view [3].](https://cloud.google.com/speech-to-text/docs/quickstart-client-libraries)